# How to remove escape character in awk?

Tags: string, awk, replace, concatenation

I am trying to concat two strings in awk. One of them seems to contain '\r':

```
stringA = "Hello\r"
stringB = "Hi"
print stringA stringB
```

results in

```
Hillo
```

What can I do to remove the '\r' if I can't change the source of stringA?

Thanks :)

Comment: Wild guess - stringA is being populated by reading the contents of a file. If so, just run dos2unix or similar on that input file before running awk on it or if you're using gawk then set `RS='\r?\n'` or run `sub(/\r/,"")` on each input line or....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {s1="Hello\r"; s2="Hi"; print s1 s2}'
Hillo
```

Just replace the carriage return `\r` with [`gsub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {s1="Hello\r"; s2="Hi"; gsub(/\r$/,"",s1); print s1 s2}'
HelloHi
```

That is, `gsub(/\r$/,"",s1)` looks for the `\r` at the end of the string `s1` and replaces it with `""`, that is, it removes it.

If multiple carriage returns appear, just get rid of the `$` so that it doesn't just match the one at the end of the line.

Ed Morton suggests in comments that probably just one carriage return will appear in a string, which is quite reasonable. If this is the case, just use `sub()` instead: `sub(/\r$/,"",s1)`.